# Windows 8.1 Store App: FadeInThemeAnimation when page loads

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to do a fade in page transition. The fade out transition works but when I try to do a fade in it doesn't seem to do anything, or perhaps is too fast.

My XAML Code:

```
<Page
x:Class="CYBOracleProject.Chapter1_1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CYBOracleProject"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeInTransition">
        <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartPage1" />
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="StartPage1" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Image Source="Image/hallway.jpg" Stretch="Fill" />
</Grid>
```

For the EventHandler I tried Loaded but it didn't work.

Comment: i have some problem with Win10!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this using the Behaviors SDK using `ControlStoryboardAction`

If you want to do it from code-behind use `DoubleAnimation` with the `Opacity` property instead of `FadeInThemeAnimation`.

**XAML**

```
<Storyboard x:Name="FadeInTransition">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartPage1"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.0"
                         To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>
```

**Loaded event:**

```
FadeInTransition.Begin();
```

Comment: yeah this works, but the question is how to use the fadeinthemeanimation.  This simple animation isn't the same.